# Why is dynamic SQL not working with bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, bulkinsert

I need to incorporate variables instead of hard-coded file name in bulk insert query so that file name is retrieved through input parameter of a stored procedure.

I tried the following code:

```
DECLARE       @sql   VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE       @fileDate     VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE       @filePath     VARCHAR(100);

SET @fileDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS date);
SET @filePath = 'D:\BI-SCRIPTS\Nauman\test.csv';

SET @sql = 
        N'BULK INSERT MMBL_phase2.dbo.auto_test' + 'FROM ''' + @filePath + '''' +
        ' WITH(
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
        );'

        EXEC (@sql);
```

But it gives the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5

> Incorrect syntax near 'D:\BI-SCRIPTS\Nauman\test.csv'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give One Space after `BULK INSERT MMBL_phase2.dbo.auto_test `. resulting of dynamic code not having space before `FROM`

Comment: Make a swlect @sql and run the code  im ss.ms, then problem should be obvious, i wozl guuess that it is tje single qurirs

Comment: You can use PRINT to check what is the result of your dynamic SQL.

Comment: The easiest way to debug dynamic SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the statement first. Then you can debug that SQL and solve the problem before propagating the solution to your SQL that generates the dynamic statement. Often you'll find that the problems are quite simple, such as a typographical error that is difficult to spot in the literal strings; for example a missing whitespace/linebreak, or leading/trailing delimiters. Taking the time to get the non-dynamic statement working first is really important, as if that doesn't work the dynamic one will have no chance of working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has been modified Missing spaces in dynamically generating query.

```
DECLARE       @sql   VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE       @fileDate     VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE       @filePath     VARCHAR(100);

SET @fileDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS date);
SET @filePath = 'D:\BI-SCRIPTS\Nauman\test.csv';

SET @sql = 
    N'BULK INSERT MMBL_phase2.dbo.auto_test' + ' FROM ''' + @filePath + '''' +
    ' WITH(
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
    );'

    EXEC (@sql);
```